# Linux segmentation fault не на всех пользователях

Tags: c++, linux, unix, boost, segmentation-fault

На VDS лежит самописная программка (на С++), при запуске исполняемого бинарника из под root - работает корректно. Стоит зайти за другого пользователя и попытаться запустить этот же бинарник, вылетает "Segmentation fault". Программа собрана на месте (на VDS).

**ОС: CentOS 7 x64**

При этом на ноуте с х32 линуксом и на ПК с х64 Win10 (собрана под свою систему отдельно, конечно же) работает без ошибок.

В чём состоит программа и её код - по сути не важно, возможно там и есть баг/утечка, но главный вопрос - как и почему на одной системе вообще возможно такое, что от одного пользователя отрабатывает чисто, от других - Segmentation fault? В чём может быть проблема? В программе пользователи ОС вообще никак не задействованы. Используются **boost_filesystem** и **tinyxpath**.

Comment: когда говорите "из-под root" - вы имеете ввиду что запускаете прогу с помощью `sudo`?

Comment: @Andrej Levkovitch нет, захожу в систему под пользователем root

Comment: обычно под root-ом имеют ввиду суперпользователя, а не имя конкретного пользователя

Comment: судя по всему ваша прога требует прав суперпользователя. Попытайтесь запустить ее с помощью sudo

Comment: @Andrej Levkovitch а как сказать что я именно авторизовался как root, чтобы было понятно? Я просто не экспертный линуксоид, заранее извиняюсь если ввёл в заблуждение.

Comment: ну так что, получилось запустить ее с помощью `sudo`?

Comment: @Andrej Levkovitch вы были правы, программа отрабатывает либо если авторизоваться как root, либо от другого пользователя но через sudo. Я покопался и выяснил, что в коде создаётся поток на файл с правами 0644 и владелец которого root, таким образом открыть его не рутом программа не может и создается указатель на "битый" поток и дальше с ним идёт работа без проверки что он указывает на реальный файл. Отсюда и segfault.

Comment: boost: fs::ofstream mystream(путь_до_файла); - вот в этой части не убедился, что файл реально открылся для записи.

Comment: проверка рута : getuid() == 0 или geteuid